# should i add filters to a zend form used for input?

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, zend-framework

After being enlightened that by using prepared statements I shouldn't filter/sanitize data being saved to the DB only on its way out.

Should I be adding filters like htmlEntities or htmlspecialchars to zend forms?

Kind Regards,

Comment: If your data might contain HTML that you don't want rendered as HTML (and to avoid [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks, this should **always** be the case if the data came from an untrusted source like a user), then yes - you will need to ensure that such data has at very least been escaped for HTML tags.  Zend Forms can do this for you with [`Zend_Filter_HtmlEntities `](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.set.html#zend.filter.set.htmlentities), although [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2051970/623041) suggests doing things yourself.